# Android Gradle custom task per variant

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, android-productflavors

I have an Android app built with Gradle, which contains BuildTypes and Product Flavors (variants).
I can for example run this command to build a specific apk:

```
./gradlew testFlavor1Debug
./gradlew testFlavor2Debug
```

I have to create a custom task in the build.gradle per variant, for example:

```
./gradlew myCustomTaskFlavor1Debug
```

I have created a task for this:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    task ("myCustomTask${variant.name.capitalize()}") {
        println "*** TEST ***"
        println variant.name.capitalize()
    }
}
```

My problem is that this task is called for ALL the variants, not the only one I am running.
Output:

```
./gradlew myCustomTaskFlavor1Debug

*** TEST ***
Flavor1Debug
*** TEST ***
Flavor1Release
*** TEST ***
Flavor2Debug
*** TEST ***
Flavor2Release
```

Expected output:

```
./gradlew myCustomTaskFlavor1Debug

*** TEST ***
Flavor1Debug
```

How can I define a custom task, dynamic, per variant, and then call it with the right variant?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It happens because the logic is executed at *configuration* time. Try adding an action (`<<`):

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    task ("myCustomTask${variant.name.capitalize()}") << {
        println "*** TEST ***"
        println variant.name.capitalize()
    }
}
```

Comment: I just discovered it by my self :( thanks for the tip anyway!

Answer (score 4):

Following Opal's answer and the [deprecation](https://docs.gradle.org/3.2/release-notes.html#the-left-shift-operator-on-the-task-interface) of `<<` operator since Gradle 3.2, the correct answer should be:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    task ("myCustomTask${variant.name.capitalize()}") {
        // This code runs at configuration time

        // You can for instance set the description of the defined task
        description = "Custom task for variant ${variant.name}"

        // This will set the `doLast` action for the task..
        doLast {
            // ..and so this code will run at task execution time
            println "*** TEST ***"
            println variant.name.capitalize()
        }
    }
}
```